# How to get data from specific input file format skipping line with scanf

Tags: c

I have a `.txt` file that contains info like this:

```
9:0
B1 0 0 0 0 0 
B2 0 0 0 0 0 
B3 4 5 0 0 0 
B4 1 2 3 0 0 
9:1
B1 0 0 0 0 0 
B2 0 0 0 0 0 
B3 4 5 0 0 0 
B4 1 2 3 0 0 
9:2
B1 0 0 0 0 0 
B2 0 0 0 0 0 
B3 4 5 0 0 0 
B4 1 2 3 0 0 
(...)
```

As you can see, the format is a line with the time, and the next four lines is the identifier of "B" followed by five elements of an array.
I can easily read the whole file, looping through the whole file (I know how many lines the file has) using first of all `scanf` to get the date, next another `scanf` to read the "B" plus the identifier, and loop four times with `scanf` again to get the integers of the array and go back to get the time.

This works fine, but (again) as you can see, there's a lot of zeros in the array space, and it would be a lot faster if I check the first element and if it is zero, then skip and read the next box, so I did it and used the `break;` statement, but the problem is that using `break` will ruin the structure of my loop, storing in the `time` variable a `B` identifier sometimes.

I'm wondering if there's any other way to skip the zeros when I find one, and jump to the next `B` identifier, i.e. after reading 9:0, i get `B1` and then read the first zero, so skip this line and get 'B2' until I find a non-empty array.
If anyone could help me, please!

Comment: Please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you think your more complicated solution would be any faster? "Skipping" to the next line involved reading all the same line anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a reasonably fast solution might be to read the entire line into a static char array, skipping to the next line if the 4'th character is 0, and using `sscanf` to read the values otherwise.

My reasoning here is that the work of `fscanf` is split between (1) reading in a string from a file, and (2) parsing that string into numbers, and moving them into the provided variables. However, I know IO operations can be pretty slow, so here is another alternative that does slightly less IO.

Use `fscanf` to read in only the first two tokens of a line (namely, the `B_` and the first number), and use `fseek` to skip to the next line if the first number is 0. I'm not super confident that this will be faster, but its something you could try.

Comment: Oh, right! I didn't knew about fseek function. It helped me. It won't be super faster but my input is from 1 to 20 (in the example y just used n=5 so there are five zeros) so skipping 19 zeros is great.